# Build bundle using xcodebuild

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcodebuild

I am building a static library. That library relies on a resource bundle that is another target in the same project. I am trying to create a Run Script, that will generate the resource bundle   every time I am building the static library and puts it into same folder. With this script I managed to do that for iOS Simulator:

```
xcodebuild -target LibsResources -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}"
```

But for some reason this script also generates empty build folder ("build/MyLib.build") at the root of the project. Why and how I can disable it?

Bonus question: How I can specify the sdk(-sdk iphonesimulator or -sdk iphoneos) in the script so it changes depending if the library is built against iSO simulator or iOS Device?

Comment: Isn't that a static framework, rather than a static library?

Comment: no, I am creating static library with a resource bundle separately

Comment: But perhaps you *should* be creating a static framework so that the relationship is more concrete?

Comment: Unfortunately it is a requirement

Comment: Why someone is down-voting question without any reason?! If you don't like something, then ask first.

Comment: @sash did you find the answer to this problem ?